HuggingFace pipeline - Debug prompt
I've defined a pipeline using Huggingface transformer library.
pipe = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=myllm,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    max_new_tokens=512,
)

I'd like to test it:
result = pipe("Some input prompt for the LLM")

How can I debug the prompt actually sent to the LLM?
I expect the pipeline to apply the prompt template (tokenizer.default_chat_template) but how can I verify how the prompt is after the template has been applied?

you may use preprocess method and check generated token_ids. Generally would suggest to more closely look on the code of the method, it will explain what is happening with the prompt before model forward pass.
params = pipe._preprocess_params

pipe.preprocess("I can't believe you did such a ", **params)

# Returns:
# {'input_ids': tensor([[  40,  460,  470, 1975,  345,  750,  884,  257,  220]]), 
# 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]), 
# 'prompt_text': "I can't believe you did such a "}

Internally preprocess is calling either

for chats tokenizer.chat_template
for simple text prompts tokenizer(prompt_text).

For example for "gpt-2" model default tokenizer outputs token_ids and masks:
pipe.tokenizer("I can't believe you did such a ")

# Returns:
# {'input_ids': [40, 460, 470, 1975, 345, 750, 884, 257, 220], 
# 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}


Another thing to consider during prompts debug is to look what will happen if you'll invert token ids:
pipe = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model="openai-community/gpt2"
)

inputs = pipe.tokenizer("I can't believe you did such a ")

pipe.tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(inputs['input_ids'])

# ['I', 'Ġcan', "'t", 'Ġbelieve', 'Ġyou', 'Ġdid', 'Ġsuch', 'Ġa', 'Ġ']


Thanks for the suggestions, I'm running some test! As a side comment: this is true for newer versions of transformer library. The old one I've been using (4.36) has a dedicated pipeline for chat ("conversational").
Took some time to realize this :)

Let me know if you'll need any more help or will found smth interesting while debugging prompts in v4.36.

Thanks Johnny, I'm trying to apply a default prompt template to a simple string, without providing a list of messages. But this is a different topic: most probably I'll open a dedicated question.
